# Any quotient of a compactly generated space is compactly generated

Tags: general-topology, locally-compact-groups

I found a note about compactly generated. This is the article http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~franklan/Math535_1205.pdf.

I worry whether the proof of Proposition 2.4 is true. I not understand why the function $\tilde{q}$ from $X$ to $kY$ is continuous. I thought that the Proposition 2.4 is valid whenever $X$ is Hausdorff. But in that note, $X$ may be not a Haudorff space.

Can someone tell me?

Answer (score 2):

That's what you could call the *universal property* of compactly generated spaces (I'll call them *$c$-spaces* for convenience):

> If $X$ is a $c$-space and $Y$ is any space, then $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if $f':X\to kY$, given by the same set map, is continuous.
>   *Proof.* Since the topology on $kY$ is finer than that on $Y$, one direction is clear. So assume $f:X\to Y$ is continuous. Since $X$ is a $c$-space, it suffices to show that $f'|_K:K\to kY$ is continuous whenever $K\subseteq X$ is compact. We know that $f|_K:X\to Y$ is continuous. But $Y$ and $kY$ have exactly the same continuous maps from compact spaces into them, so $f'|_K$ is continuous, and this means that $f'$ is.

Depending on how much category theory you know, you may understand this as the fact that the inclusion functor from the category of $c$-spaces to the category of all spaces has a right adjoint, the $k$-ification, with the counit being the identity $kY\to Y$.

Comment: I have a problem to prove $f'|_K:K\rightarrow kY$ is continuous for every compact subset $K\subseteq X$.

Let $U$ be open in $kY$ and $K$ compact subset of $X$,

$(f'|_K)^{-1}(U)=(f')^{-1}(U)\cap K=(f)^{-1}(U)\cap K$.

How do you guarantee that the preimage $(f)^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$? Since $U$ may be not open in $Y$.

Comment: @flourence: If $K$ is compact, then $f(K)$ is compact. So if $U$ is open in $kY$, then $U\cap f(K)$ is open in $f(K)$, thus $f|_K^{-1}(U)$ is open in $K$.

Comment: I still don't understand  why $(f|_K)^{-1}(U)$ is open.

A map $f|_K$ is a continuous mapping from a compact subset $K$ to $Y$. Since $U$ is open in $kY$ (may be not in $Y$), $(f|_K)^{-1}(U)$ may be not open in $K$.

I know $f(K)$ is a compact subset of $Y$. But since we still do not know whether $Y$ is a $c$-space, we cannot conclude $U$ is open in $Y$.

Comment: @flourence: The map $f|_K$ is a continuous map from $K$ to $f(K)$, and if $U$ is $k$-open in $Y$, then $U\cap f(K)$ is open in $f(K)$ since that set is compact. But then its preimage under $f|_K$ is open in $K$.

Comment: $U\cap f(K)$ is open in $f(K)\subseteq Y$ doesn't imply $U$ is open in $Y$. So, I worry, how you can get its preimage under $f|_K$ is open in $K$.

If $Y$ is a Hausdorff space, then we can conclude that $U$ is open in $Y$. Hence $(f|_K)^{-1}(U)$ is open in $K$.

Comment: @flourence: No, but it implies that its preimage under $f|_K:K\to f(K)$ is open in $K$.

Answer (score 0):

If $Y$ is a Hausdorff space then $kY=Y$. Let $\tilde{q}=q$. Thus, $\tilde{q}$ is continuous