# Let $f:X \to Y$ be a quotient map and $X$ and $Y$ hausdorff spaces, where $X$ is compactly generated. Why is $Y$ then compactly generated?

Tags: general-topology

This question is related to this one:

[Any quotient of a compactly generated space is compactly generated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1286296/any-quotient-of-a-compactly-generated-space-is-compactly-generated)

The difference is that I assume the spaces to be hausdorff additionally. So I was wondering, if there is an easier way to prove the statement then without using this machinery then. Basically, a simple proof fails because I cannot say that $f^{-1} (K) $ is compact for $K \subset Y$ compact in my opinion. Do you have any hints or suggestions about that problem?

Comment: But I only assume $X$ to be compactly generated. Are compactly generated hausdorff spaces compact in general?

Comment: Oops, sorry, missed that point. I should delete that comment.